# user folder and all my desktop files were deleted

Tags: windows-7

i have to give project tomorrow but accidentally I go to user folder> properties 
 and from attributes part i choose read only and hidden both and apply the processes. Something happened after that and all the user folder were deleted. 
please please help me. emergency

Comment: Use **folder options** to unhide the hidden files and then remove the **read only** attribute

Comment: did you try some elementary research? like googling "folder hidden properties"?

Answer (score 1):

Two are a couple ways you can get back into your folder.

The first is by simply typing the location into the path bar in an Explorer Window:

[image]

In the screenshot above, you can see that I am currently in 'Folder' and have one 'Not Hidden Folder'. There is also a folder called 'Hidden Folder' here. So typing the path `~\Folder\Hidden Folder` will allow me to get into a folder that has been hidden.

To actually **unhide** the folder you have accidentally hidden.

Open an Explorer window and use `Tool > Folder Options...` to get to the folder View settings.

[image]

Simply click the radio button beside `Show hidden files, folders, and drives` to reveal your hidden folder.

Remember to set this back if you don't want to always see hidden files and folders.